# What is the difference between 'ceremonial' and 'ceremonious'?

Tags: meaning, semantics, differences

Even having looked in the OED I am still slightly unclear as to which contexts require the adjective *ceremonious* and which *ceremonial*.

The OED treatment of *ceremonious* is as below with some of the more recent examples. You will notice that in sense 1 it is equated to *ceremonial*. However sense 5 suggests a slightly different meaning.

> 1. Pertaining to, or consisting of, ceremonies or outward forms and rites; = ceremonial adj., formal.
>
> 1737   D. Waterland Rev. Doctr. Eucharist 443   Ceremonious
>   Observances.
>
> 2. Full of ceremony; accompanied with rites, religious or showy.
>
> 1883   Manch. Examiner 14 Dec. 5/2   A statue has been raised to
>   him..and there was a ceremonious unveiling.
>
> 3. According to prescribed or customary formalities or punctilios.
>
> 1863   M. Howitt tr. F. Bremer Greece & Greeks II. xi,   His..somewhat
>   ceremonious politeness.
>
> †4. According to the Ceremonial Law. Obs.
>
> 1656   S. Winter Serm. 120   The holiness of children, which some say
>   was ceremonious.
>
> 5. Of persons: Addicted to ritual observances (obs.); given to ceremony; punctilious in observance of formalities, esp. those of
>      intercourse between ranks or persons.
>
> 1829   K. H. Digby Broad Stone of Honour: Godefridus xviii. 223   The
>   ceremonious and ungrateful courtiers of Vienna.

Comment: *Ceremonial* is far more common. I think *ceremonious* could often be used as a synonym, but in practice when it *is* used, it's more likely to be much more figurative. Thus a *ceremonial speech* would normally be one actually delivered as part of a formal ceremony, whereas a *ceremonious speech* is more likely to be just one that *sounds* like that. But that's just an opinion. I can't see anything in the full OED making that distinction obvious.

Comment: Generally, *people* are *ceremonious* in their *manner* of doing things; *objects* employed in ceremonies are *ceremonial* objects.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes, on further reflection I think that OED sense 5 of *ceremonious* largely confirms what you have said. But it was the equals sign in sense 1 which was confusing me. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I agree but the distinction is not simply between people and objects. People behave ceremonially when engaged in ceremonies. But as for old Uncle Bert, he has a *ceremonious* way of greeting people at the door, even the postman.

Answer (score 7):

The two terms [ceremonial and  cerimonious](http://commonerrorscalendar.blogspot.it/2012/02/ceremonialceremonious-entry-for.html) have the same root "*cerinomy*" but meaning and usage are different even though they are often incorrectly used as synonyms:

> - “Ceremonial” and “ceremonious” are often considered synonyms, and can indeed be used interchangeably in many contexts. But there are some cases in which one is better than the other.
> - ***If you are talking about the performance of a ceremony, the word you will usually want is “ceremonial”*** as in “ceremonial offering,” “ceremonial garb,” or “ceremonial dance.” Sikhs traditionally wear ceremonial daggers.
> - ***“Ceremonious” is mostly used to describe formal behavior which often has little or no connection with a literal ceremony***: “ceremonious manners,” “ceremonious welcome,” or “ceremonious speech.”

(Common Errors in English Usage)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ceremonial%2Cceremonious%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cceremonial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cceremonious%3B%2Cc0): ceremonial vs ceremonious

[Cerimonial](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Ceremonial%20&searchmode=none):

> - ***c. 1400, "belonging to (religious) ritual,"*** also as a noun, "a ceremonial practice," from Late Latin caerimonialis ***"pertaining to ceremony,*** " from caerimonia (see ceremony).

[Ceremonious](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ceremonious&allowed_in_frame=0) :

> - ***1550s, from Middle French cérémonieux or directly from Late Latin caerimoniosus, from Latin caerimonia (see [cerimony](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ceremony&allowed_in_frame=0))***. Meaning "full of show and ceremony" is from 1610s.

Etymonline

Comment: +1 Yes. You give a fundamentally similar answer to that of @Fumble Fingers' comment.

Comment: I didn't read his comment first, I just  gave my answer.

Comment: The meaning of two terms tend to overlap here: ***Ceremonious***:   *Relating or appropriate to grand and formal occasions:*
"a Great Hall where ceremonious and public appearances were made" ***Ceremonial***  *Relating to or used for formal religious or public events:*
"a ceremonial occasion".  (ODO)

Comment: And still, with the meaning cited above *ceremonial* is the more commonly used term:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ceremonious+occasion%2Cceremonial+occasion&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cceremonious%20occasion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cceremonial%20occasion%3B%2Cc0

Comment: My apologies. I didn't mean to imply that you had plagiarised @Fumble Fingers comment. I mentioned it just to indicate that another contributor of repute was saying something very similar to your good self. And yes you make a good point that there is overlap.

Comment: @WS2: If I *had* been, I'd be perfectly happy to be plagiarised. And in fact, I'm more than happy in this case - partly because it agrees with my gut feeling, but mainly because Josh61 has made such a good job of locating and presenting credible references. I only looked at OED, where it would be more accurate to say there's nothing *undermining* the distinction as made here, but there's nothing explicitly supporting it either (Defn 5 under *ceremonious* is partly marked "obsolete", and that same sense matches Defn A2 under *ceremonial*, which is also thus flagged).